# Prove or disprove statement about cardinality of union

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I am attempting to prove or come up with a counterexample for the following statement:

> If $|A\cup A'|=\aleph_\alpha$, then either $|A|=\aleph_\alpha$ or
>   $|A'|=\aleph_\alpha$.

Here, $\aleph_\alpha$ are the so-called [aleph numbers.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number)

This seems true at least for $\alpha=0$ (the union of two finite sets cannot be countably infinite), but obviously there could be some other $\alpha$ for which this is false. Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: HINT: $\aleph_\alpha+\aleph_\beta=\aleph_{\max\{\alpha,\beta\}}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am aware of this fact, but I can't quite see how this helps. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Let $|A|=\aleph_\beta$ and $|A'\setminus A|=\aleph_\gamma$. Then $|A\cup A'|=\aleph_\beta+\aleph_\gamma$, so $\max\{\beta,\gamma\}=\alpha$.

Comment: Ah so then either $\beta=\alpha$ or $\gamma=\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If $\beta=\alpha$ you’re done, and if $\gamma=\alpha$ there’s just a little work still to be done.

Comment: Done! It’s always nice to get a question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $|A|=\aleph_\beta$ and $|A'\setminus A|=\aleph_\gamma$. Then $|A\cup A'|=\aleph_\beta+\aleph_\gamma$, so $\max\{\beta,\gamma\}=\alpha$. If $\beta=\alpha$, you’re done, and if $\gamma=\alpha$, there’s just a little more work to be done.